# Loading an image through PHP

Tags: php, image, mime-types

I'm trying to load an image through PHP, but I don't know how.
The filename is stored in the database, such as `image.jpg`

```
if($_GET['image']){
    // Client requesting image, so retrieve it from DB
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['image']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
}
```

The client needs to request an image like so

```
http://example.com/index.php?image=1
```

And then it should return the image, so it can be embedded like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/index.php?image=1" alt="" />
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$img = 'path/to/image.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($img);
```

just tested it

Comment: Also have a look at [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) it "combines" the `file_get_contents` and `echo` steps.

Comment: make sure you don't have any extra space before opening the <?php tag, It would mess up with the file content... made me waste precious time

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GD library for that. You start by creating a resource using a function like `http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg`. You will need to provide the path as a parameter.

After that, you just output the resource using a function like `http://php.net/imagejpeg`.

Don't forget to send the content type header, and also to use `imagedestroy` on the resource.

Update:

Consider this sample:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('path/to/image.jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: @safarov maybe it would make it easier to extend if certain modifications are needed.. I did not say it is the only way, I just suggested an option..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first make a file called image.php. So you will call image.php?id=1

Have image.php header be the image type. header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

Then you can use the GDImage library in PHP to load the image, and output it. Or you can read the file and output it. The header() is key.