# setInterval - load PHP with POST - return image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `setInterval()` to reload an image from a given path. I have some similar code to reload a log file which is working fine:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function auto_refresh_log()
    {
        $('#log_output').load('refresh_log.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000);
```

refresh_log.php:

```
<?php  $file = "/var/www/html/mainLOG";     
    $contents =  file($file);   
    $string = implode( $contents);  
    echo $string; ?>
```

Now, I want to do something similar only with 2 changes:

- Instead of using a fixed path like in refresh_log.php, I want to pass the path from the JS function to the PHP file. How can I do that?
- Instead of returning a string, I want to return an image, which is then used in my html document. How can I do that?

To be exact on what I want to do: I have an index.php on which a user can select a file path. After setting some further parameters, some calculations start in the background. The results are saved as TIFF-files which cannot be read by the browser. So I want to use a PHP script with `imagemagick` to convert them (which is working fine) and pass them back to the JS. Then, the image should be displayed on my HTML `<img id="image_id" ... >` and refreshed every couple of seconds just like the log file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

The browser will download the resource when you change the the `src` of the `img` element. Use the jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to do this. You should append a timestamp parameter so the browser does not obtain a cached instance from the local browser cache.

```
function loadImg(src) {
    // append a parameter of "_" to the url
    $("#myimg").attr("src", src + "?_=" + Date.now());
}
setInterval(loadImg("path/to/img"), 1000);
```

On your PHP side you would need a script that servers the image up in your converted format from where ever you are storing it. An example of how to do that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959148/5550503).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a solution using `$.post` instead of `$.load`. The function is called via:

```
setInterval(
    function auto_refresh_img()
    {
        var img_path = document.getElementById("image_path").value;         
        $.post('refresh_img.php', 
                {path: img_path}, 
                function(data) {
                     $('#my_div').html(data);}
              );
    }, 1000);
```

with `refresh_img.php` looking like this:

```
<?php $imagepath = $_REQUEST['path'];

if (file_exists($imagepath))  {

    $img = new imagick($imagepath."[0]");
    $img->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $thumbnails0 = $img->getImageBlob();

    echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($thumbnails0)."'  id='reco_background' style='display:none'   />";
}
else {
    echo "Image does not exist.";
    };
?>
```

The returned `<img ... >` may then be used for any purpose.